# Copy Dependencies for Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am trying to get the subset of the gradle cache that is needed for my specific project build and nothing else. Is there a way for me to separate only the needed dependencies and place them into a new cache that could be specified as the new gradle home?

I tried using some of the copyDependnecies tasks but I found that it wouldn't copy the plugin dependencies and even if I manually copy the plugin dependencies I can't specify those dependencies in my build.gradle and they aren't able to be recognized by a gradle flatDir.

```
task copyDeps(type: Copy) {
   from configurations.compile // can be different conf name
   into 'libs'
}
```

Does anyone know if there is any way to just quickly create the subset of the gradle cache? I am also worried about cleaning the cache and just building again for the case that there are locally defined packages that are being called and aren't able to be accessed though the internet.